# Installed Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) which contains Python 3.6 but pip3 missing, cannot install tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I downloaded the latest stable Anaconda install off the Continuum website which turned out to be Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) and comes with Python 3.6.0. I am in a Windows 10 environment.

However pip3 is missing and I cannot install any Python 3.x packages via pip3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Install pip3 ... or use pip ... or use pip3.6

Comment: I have updated in order to get tensorflow 1.0.1 in python 3.6, alternatively just virtualenv 3.5 and use pip

Comment: As @Claudio has suggested using the command: **pip install --upgrade tensorflow** will also work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not have another environment installed python 3+ will default to just pip I believe since pip3 is just an alias for pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or You can do it with the associated Python binary too; if it executable as python3, then use that:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after that check:

```
pip --version
```

otherwise just try `pip-3.6`

for tensorflow on conda:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

for python 3.6 due to conda providing the 3.5 one: [from](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6533)

```
pip install https://testpypi.python.org/packages/db/d2/876b5eedda1f81d5b5734277a155fa0894d394a7f55efa9946a818ad1190/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Since this wheel had a version that is undesirable we could instead install 
the wheel directly from gohlke's windows binaries repository :
download the wheel for python 3.6 from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow) and then install the wheel:

`cd` to the directory containing `.whl` file:

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

Comment: `C:\>pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu` resulted in 
  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: C:\>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: pip-3.6 is not recognized

Comment: `pip install tensorflow-gpu` gives the following error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Well, thats what I did in my original question and it outputs and error, is not working.

Comment: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I believe there might just not be one for python 3.6 in conda forge, so the one we used was the wrong one, I'm updating the answer

Comment: Which version of tensorflow is that wheel in your updated answer? I am asking because it looks as if its version 0.12.1 but current version is 1.0.1?

Comment: the version is 0.12.1

Comment: thanks for your prompt help but how would I go about if I would definitely wanted to use the newest tensorflow version. That has priority over the python version I am using

Comment: In order to install version 1.0.1 I assume I need Python 3.5, correct? Would I need to install an older Anaconda version that ships with Python 3.5 and not 3.6?

Comment: Ha, great find @SerialDev, will try it out right away, thanks already for all those tips, and in case its not apparent, I am a bloody beginner when it comes to Python.

Comment: installing...fingers crossed

Comment: works! You are the man. Thanks a lot @SerialDev, even within Jupyter Notebook. Excellent. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

easy_install pip

I used it, for the problem of pip installation in miniconda. 
sometimes the pip is not properly installed but it claims yes

Comment: Please try to put the stack trace of error message when asking questions so that people can easily debug it

Answer (score 0):

Solution:- (Note:- This will surely work for all!!)

Step 1:- conda search python

Step 2:- conda install python=3.5.2

Step 3:- pip install tensorflow

Step 4:- import tensorflow as tf

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows10, 64bit, Anaconda4.3 with Python 3.6.

Karthik' soluton worked for me. Before that I tried everything including "conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5", but it did not work (although "python --version" gave 3.5.3).

Comment: Obviously that would be difficult to be the case. As you can see Karthik specified python version 3.52 which may or may not work. I wanted version 3.6 and his solution does not work for reasons discussed in the comment section of the accepted answer

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, sorry. Python 3.6 is not supported, it is clear from the comments before and the Tensorflow site ("TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows"). My point was that I tried various options to install TF with Python 3.5  (including the installation guide from TensorFlow site) but nothing worked. What worked is exactly those 4 steps suggested by Karthik (using "conda install python=3.5.2").

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to install tensorflow using

`$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`