# I Have an Anaconda distribution of python and there is a pip installed with it, but no pip3

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

what is the difference between pip and pip3? since I type

```
pip -V
```

it displays the version of pip which is

```
pip 20.0.2
```

but when I type pip3:

```
pip3: command not found
```

Someone suggests install python 3 again by homebrew, but I don't want to install 2 python on the computer just to get pip3, is there anyway to get over it?

Comment: Are you on linux? If so, I believe you can call it directly with `/usr/bin/pip3 -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installed Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) which contains Python 3.6 but pip3 missing, cannot install tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412245/installed-anaconda-4-3-1-64-bit-which-contains-python-3-6-but-pip3-missing-ca)

Comment: The pip/pip3 distinction shouldn't be an issue in a Conda environment. Be careful when using pip, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.